# how do I select words with a particular structure from a file in a shell script?

Tags: shell, grep

My file has this structure:

```
    HELLO h e l lo
    HELLO(2) h ee l lo
    HELLOMUM h e l ll m um
    HELLO-FATHER h e llo fa th er
    HOME h o m e
    HONEY h o ne y
    HONEY(2) ho nei y
    HONEY(3) h o ney
    HONEYMOON ho ney m o o n
    HONEY-MOON h o ne y moo n
```

I would like, while looking for the word HELLO, for example, to extract only the lines relatives to the words HELLO and HELLO(2). Same thing if I am looking for the word HONEY, I would like to have only the lines relative to HONEY, HONEY(2) and HONEY(3). 
I am using

```
grep -w "HELLO" file.txt
```

but this gives me back for HELLO, for example, also the lines relative to HELLOMUM and HELLO-FATHER.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this should work for you.

```
grep '^HELLO[^a-zA-Z]' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> grep '^HELLO[^a-zA-Z\-]' temp
HELLO h e l lo
HELLO(2) h ee l lo
> grep '^HONEY[^a-zA-Z\-]' temp
HONEY h o ne y
HONEY(2) ho nei y
HONEY(3) h o ney
>
```

Comment: Thank you! this works, but I also have words like HELLO_FATHER, which I did not notice before. How should I change the code to avoid to select them as well?

Thank you again!

Comment: well you need to use `grep '^HELLO[^a-zA-Z]' your_file` for getting hello-father too

Comment: down vote? I did not even realize. I am sorry. But no, what I meant is that I want to avoid to take words like HELLO_FATHER. we first consider only HELLO-FATHER case.

Comment: I changed the down vote.. sorry again: it was a random click.

Answer (score 1):

take your pasted example as file, the following grep line works:

```
grep 'HELLO[( ]' file
grep 'HONEY[( ]' file
```